# How to put custom content like a linebreak inside p:column header

Tags: css, primefaces, jsf-2, line-breaks

In my application, I have the following `<p:dataTable>`:

[image: data table]

The 2nd column's header costs too much spaces. Hence, I'd like to put a linebreak between `Number of` & `Sessions` and also vertically align the headers of the table. I tried to reduce the width of the column but it didn't automatically result in a linebreak.

Besides, since the header name is retrieved from the `l10n.properties` file, I also tried to set it as `Number of /n Sessions` but `/n` was printed out as a normal string.

**UPDATE:** I also tried to set the property as `Number of <br/> Sessions`. However, in the HTML code generated, `<br/>` disappeared and the table looks exactly the same as above.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an advice.

Best regards,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove the `headerText` attribute from the column and add a header facet inside it:

```
/*  no_of_sessions = Number of &#10; Sessions  */
<p:column ... >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{l10n.no_of_sessions}" 
                  escape="false" style="white-space:pre-line;" />
    </f:facet>
    ...
</p:column>
```

The `escape="false"` is relevant so html is escaped, then you can put anything you want in there. If you just want to style content, this is not needed

Comment: Thanks! just to clarify, it works for me by removing the 'headerText' attribute of the column, and adding the facet element inside the column

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputLabel value="Number of&#10;Sessions" style="white-space:pre;"/>
</f:facet>
```

If using the "Number of Sessions" from properties file, try the below in your properties file ...

```
myString = Number of \
           Sessions
```

Comment: I have just tried your solution. Instead of putting a linebreak between `Number of` and `Sessions`, the linebreak was created at the beginning of the phrase. As a result, there is an empty line and the whole `Number of Sessions` was moved to the 2nd line. :(

Comment: can you post what you tried. Because, I Posted here what was working fine for me and of course I was using IE.

Comment: if you are accessing 'Number of Sessions' from properties file, try using back slash as mentioned in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If it's CSS, you could have a `<br/>` tag after 'Number of'.
I just saw your edited post.

What you're doing in Firebug is actually 'editing text'
However, what you need to do is 'Right click' and then 'Edit HTML'. This way when you insert the 
 tag, the text would break and shift onto the next line.

Comment: :).. But still, how can I retrieve it directly from the `l10n.properties` file? Somehow, `<br/>` was deleted before the whole view is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer for this is to add white-space:pre-line in the style attribute.
See the below code

```
<p:column headerText="Number of Sessions" style="white-space:pre-line;width:50px;">
     <h:outputText value="#{value}"></h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because each word would be on one line.